# How do I add the None Dimension back to a Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

I've made some transformation in a Lambda Layer and now I have shape `(1,)`, how do I get back to `(None, 1)`?

Here are my operations

```
def function_lambda(x):
    import keras.backend

    aux_array = keras.backend.sign(x)
    #the shape is (?, 11) here OK

    aux_array = keras.backend.relu(aux_array)
    #the shape is (?, 11) here still OK

    aux_array = keras.backend.any(aux_array)
    #the shape is () here not OK

    aux_array = keras.backend.reshape(aux_array, [-1])
    #now the shape is (1,) almost OK

    return aux_array
```

How do I reshape and put back the `None` Batch Dimension?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: I'm wondering the same question.  Did you figure it out?

Comment: Hi @Hephaestus , I know this is an older question. But did you figure out what to do?

Comment: @MaltheHaveMusaeus Its been a while.  I recall the point is not to lose it.  Most operations have a `Dim=` option to specify what dimensions to work on.  Then one can carefully exclude the None dimension from being consumed.  I'll check in the next week or two to see if I found a better way.

Comment: Awesome. I'm right now using: `tf.broadcast_to(10, shape=(tf.shape(input)[0], 1))`, to return the int 10. But the problem is still that I get the exact same prediction for all input data in batch

Answer (score 2):

The tf.reshape has a limitation that it cannot work with "None" dimension. So far as I know, the only place where we can define a "None" dimension is in tf.placeholder. The following should work:

```
def function_lambda(x):
    import keras.backend

    aux_array = keras.backend.sign(x)
    #the shape is (?, 11) here OK

    aux_array = keras.backend.relu(aux_array)
    #the shape is (?, 11) here still OK

    aux_array = keras.backend.any(aux_array)
    #the shape is () here not OK

    aux_array = keras.backend.placeholder_with_default(aux_array, [None,1])
    #now the shape is (?,1) OK

    return aux_array
```

Additional note: creating a new placeholder for reintroducing the "None" dimension is useful when trying to use Google Machine Learning Engine. MLE requires that the first dimension (batch) always remain "None" or unknown.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fully-defined shape (like `(1,)`) then you don't need `None` dimensions, because you know exactly how many elements your tensor has. But you can reshape to have two dimensions replacing you reshaping with:

```
aux_array = keras.backend.reshape(aux_array, [-1, 1])
```

This will give you an array with shape `(1, 1)`, which is compatible with the shape `(None, 1)`, so it should be okay. Note that `-1` in `reshape` means "however many elements are necessary to accommodate the tensor in this shape", but in this case you know you only have one element, so it would be the same to use:

```
aux_array = keras.backend.reshape(aux_array, [1, 1])
```

Because, again, the shape is fully defined and you know what the size of each dimension should be exactly. However, using `-1` is convenient because it works whether you know the shape fully or not, and Keras/TensorFlow will work out what the size should be (the dimension will have the necessary size if it can be computed or `None` if part of the shape is unknown).

Comment: I think this is missing the point.  When defining a model to operate on tensors in Tensorflow, one generally needs the first dimension to be None or ?, to indicate the minibatch dimension. For example, `[None, 12, 12]` indicates that the first dimension is not fully specified and will be set at training time..  In this case, one does need the "None" dimension.